# How to turn OFF and ON ethernet connection on windows 10?

Tags: operating-system, windows-10, system, ethernet

Good morning !

I am using win10 on LG computer.
I would like to turn off and On ethernet in windows 10. I check airplane mode on the setting tab but there is not any airplane option

Do you know any sofware or alternative to turn on/off ethernet connection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airplane mode only works on mobile devices. To disable/enable your ethernet adapter, do the following.

Navigate to Settings->Network & Internet->Change Adapter Options. Then, right click your ethernet adapter and select either Enable or Disable (You will need Administrator privileges for this).

You can skip a step by right clicking the internet icon in your task-bar, and selecting "Open Network and Internet Settings".